# Python virtualenv ImportError: No module named 'zlib'

Tags: virtualenv, zlib, python-3.5

I am on an Ubuntu machine, which has Python 2.7.6 as its default python.  It also has Python 3.4.3, with both versions located in /usr/bin/.

I have downloaded virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.  I then downloaded the current version of Python, 3.5.1.  In its directory I ran the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make altinstall
```

Python 3.5.1 is now installed in /usr/local/bin/.

I now run the following commands:

```
mkvirtualenv test1
mkvirtualenv test2 -p /usr/bin/python3
mkvirtualenv test3 -p /usr/local/bin/python3.5
```

Environment test1 successfully created with Python version 2.7.6, and environment test2 successfully created with Python version 3.4.3.  However, test3 fails with the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
```

I see mentioned that I need to have "zlib" installed when compiling python to begin with, though make test didn't seem to give any problems.  Do I just need to download and compile zlib from www.zlib.net and recompile python3.5?

Answer (score 1):

**zlib** is a built-in module for Python 3.5.
I think you just need *re-compile* Python 3.5...

**Look that link for Python virtualenv :** 
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/3uwk76/help_using_python_in_linux/

**Get python source and extract**

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.5.0.tgz

**configure for local install**

cd Python-3.5.0/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python35
make

**If it complains about missing dependencies, install them, make clean and repeat.**

make install

Comment: And how might the asker go about doing that?

Comment: Or just : sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev ?